# display tabs in header from left to right

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React application with the following code:

```
export const AppHeaderBase: React.FunctionComponent<IAppHeaderProps> = (
  props: IAppHeaderProps
) => {
  const { className, styles } = props;
  const classNames: IProcessedStyleSet<IAppHeaderStyles> = getClassNames(
    styles,
    {
      className,
      theme: useTheme(),
    }
  );

  return (
    <header>
      <div className={classNames.root} role="banner" aria-label="header">
        <A />
        <B />
        <C/>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export const getStyles = (props: IAppHeaderStyleProps): IAppHeaderStyles => {
  const { className, theme } = props;

  return {
    root: [
      {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.themePrimary,
        height: 54,
        maxWidth: "100%",
        margin: '0 auto',
        borderBottom: '1px solid transparent',
        boxSizing: 'border-box'
      },
      className
    ]
  };
};
```

The issue is I see all these in UI vertically

```
A
B
C
```

How do I update it such that it is displayed horizontally?

```
A B C
```

Comment: add `display: 'flex'` to `className.root`'s styles.

Comment: That worked! Can I add some spaces in between these 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: flex;` to display the items horizonatlly.

Here's a good resource to learn about flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: That worked! Can I add some spaces in between these 3?

Comment: Yeah, use `gap: 10px;`